# Add a pause/interval to every iteration in a FOR LOOP

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iteration, settimeout, setinterval

I want to write a for loop which prints number 1 to 10 with intervals after every iteration *"**[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/cynNy/)**"*

How can I achieve it? I tried sleep() setInterval() setTimeout(") and what not but can't seem to find any working solution. And if possible I would like to do this using pure Javascript only.

```
function abc(){
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
        document.write(i+"<br>");
        sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: so you want to avoid using setInterval()?

Comment: What did you try using setTimeout and setInterval?  Can we see your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep

Comment: `setInterval` is actually the function you need, here.
Just keep track of a counter, and unset the interval when you've ran it X times.

Comment: @Matthew Gilliard: I got it working using this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/cynNy/1/). I was just curious to know how could I do it using FOR LOOP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question, to get something like a sleep function you could just write somehting like this as a helper function

```
function sleep(dur) {
 var d = new Date().getTime() + dur;
  while(new Date().getTime() <= d ) {
    //Do nothing
  }

}

console.log(new Date().getTime())
     sleep(1000)

 console.log(new Date().getTime())
```

Then you *could* call the `sleep` function after every iteration like

```
function abc(){
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
        document.write(i+"<br>");
        sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

But Note that `sleep` will freeze your browser in this time and
you don't really wan't this kind of behaviour when you just want to periodiccally do sth

`window.setInterval` would be what you want in such cases

```
    function abcd(i){
       document.write(i + "<br>")
    }


function repeatedTimeout(func,times,duration) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).splice(3);
    var i = 0;
    args.push(i)
    var wrap = function () {
     if(args[args.length - 1] >= times)
       window.clearInterval(wrap)
      else {

         func.apply(this,args)
         args[args.length - 1]++
       }
    }
    window.setInterval(wrap,duration)
}
repeatedTimeout(abcd,10,1000)
```

Which would call it 10 times every 1000 milliseconds, whithout freezing the Browers

Heres the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/iyaser/1/edit)

### Update

If it really has to be a for loop,  you could do something like this,
regardless of the sense it makes to me

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10 ; i++) {
  window.setTimeout(
    (function (i){ 
      return function() {
        document.write(i + "<br>")
      }
    })(i),i * 1000)
  }
```

In this case heres another [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/okusez/1/edit)

This would call `window.setTimeout` in a `for` loop and a multiple of the timeout with `i` as the timeout, 
this would work, but i'd rather suggest using `setInterval` like you already did in the Fiddle you posted in the comment

Comment: Looping in a `while(...)` will peg the CPU while the condition is true.

Comment: Thx =), I know, i added it because he asked for something like a sleep function, I  were editing the answer to point that out and add more stuff, but this took me a while

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your efforts. I made it work using this  "[CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/cynNy/1/)"

What I am really interested is in doing this using for loop. Using "Sleep" isn't necessary for me.

Comment: Why does it has to be a for loop ?

Comment: @Glutamat - This is the reason why I want to do it using FOR LOOP [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dYRR2/1/)

Comment: @user1688606 That doesn't clarify why you need a `for` loop. You should explain your reasons in your question so we're not guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the mostly asynchronous (and single threaded) nature of JavaScript in the browser, constructs such as `sleep()` aren't the way to go.

You can write a generic function using `setTimeout()` that will do the looping and then pass in the function that should be run at every interval of x milliseconds. At least you'd have a reusable container in which you can run your code.

```
function loopn(n, fn, delay)
{
    if (n > 0) {
        fn();
        if (n > 1) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                loopn(n - 1, fn, delay);
            }, delay);
        }
    }
}

loopn(10, function() {
    console.log('hello there');
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could deconstruct the loop into a recursive function and use `setTimeout` to implement the pause.

```
var i = 0;
var limit = 10;

function loop(){
    console.log(i);
    i++;
    if(i < limit)
    {

        setTimeout(loop, 100);
    }
}
loop();
​
```